# importing servlets from library in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jetty, web.xml

I have included a library in my webapp. This library has its own web.xml. When I deploy the project on jetty, I find that the servlets from the library are not loaded. I have to manually add these servlets into the web.xml of my project. Is it possible to include these servlets in my project without me having to enter them all in my web.xml

If additional information regarding my problem is required, I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell the servlet container that it has to initialize a sevlet. The usually way is to use the deployment descriptor (web.xml). Since JEE6 there is another option with annotations:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/forward")
public class ForwardServlet extends HttpServlet {
  //code goes here...
}
```

But you'll have to try it, if it works with servlets inside a referenced library.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, the annotation will have to be on the servlets in the referenced library. For me currently rewriting these servlets is not an option, which is why I was wondering if there is a way to specify the web.xml of the referenced library as well so that the container can pick up the servlets from that web.xml too.

Comment: Does that library only contain servlets, or are there other classes that you need? What exactly is that library for?

Comment: There are other classes that we need, the library itself is deployed as an independent webapp elsewhere (hence these servlets) and is a full fledged project by itself. We have built a webapp in which we import the functionality of this library as a jar plus some of our own servlets.